# avahi-daemon binds to eth0 udp ports 5353 and 53791

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, avahi

avahi-daemon continues to bind to eth0 ports 5353 and 53791. Is there any way to tell avahi-daemon to only bind to localhost and not eth0 ?

/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf

```
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=no
allow-interfaces=lo
deny-interfaces=eth0
```

netstat -nap

```
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:53791   0.0.0.0:*   3145/avahi-daemon:
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:5353    0.0.0.0:*   3145/avahi-daemon:
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? (Restricting it to `localhost` strikes me as odd...do you want to disable it completely?)  Have you had a look at the output of `avahi-daemon --debug`?

Answer (score 9):

`avahi-daemon` implements [Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) network configuration protocol.  It is useless unless it operates on network interface. You can select on which network interface you want it to run using "allow-interfaces" and "deny-interfaces" directives, but if you do not want to run in on any real network interface (as you seem), then you should not be running it at all, so simply shut it down (for example by putting `exit 0` in `/etc/default/avahi-daemon`) or even better remove the package completely if you do not plan to using it in the future.

It does not make any sense to run it only at `lo` interface.

Comment: To remove it completely: `sudo apt remove avahi-daemon avahi-discover libnss-mdns`

Comment: Good answer. But the ports are confusing. Port 5353 seems like an official, standard mdns port. But what is port 53791? Or on my system, the other port avahi-daemon is connected to is 48268, so it seems randomized and thus yet more confusing.

Comment: @nealmcb Thanks. You can find which ports are used by which program by example with `sudo netstat -tulpn`. As to **why** it happens (eg. you're interested in low-level programming methods for avahi-mdns implementation and how it relates to RFC requirements), you should ask a new question (probably on some more programming-related stackexchange site)

Answer (score 2):

according to https://wiki.debian.org/ZeroConf here's an official way to stop and disable avahi-daemon completely:

```
systemctl stop avahi-daemon.socket
systemctl stop avahi-daemon.service
systemctl disable avahi-daemon
```

make it bind to `lo` does not make any sense as pointed out by others in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of centos you could try this :https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-avahi-daemon-service-in-centos-rhel/

Turn off the service by using the following:

```
# service avahi-dnsconfd stop
# service avahi-daemon stop
```

You can make this configuration persistent across reboots by performing the following:

```
# chkconfig avahi-daemon off
# chkconfig avahi-dnsconfd off
```